# Trouble in Laravel displaying the name of a relationship object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am very new to Laravel and I am experimenting at the moment.
So I decided to try and make a relationship of a hypothetical Online product for sale which has a 'country_from' and 'country_to' field in the database. So long story short I made the relationship and whenever I make the product via the forms the data reflects in the database properly. However, when I try and display the data back (the name of the country) I get an error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object".

`Product` Model

```
protected $fillable = [

    'country_from',
    'country_to',
    'title',
    'body',
    'price',
    'availability'
];

public function countries(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

`Country` Model

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];

public static $rules = array('name'=>'required|min:3');

public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
```

`products` table: id, user_id, category_id, country_id, country_forum, country_to, photo_id, title, body, price, availability, created_at, updated_at

`countries` table: id, name, created_at, updated_at

In my blade `$product->country_from` displays the proper value of the set id.

However, when I try to: `$product->country->name` I get:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I am totally new to Laravel and PHP and my bet is I am doing something wrong with the relationship, but I have no idea what..

Comment: Have you tried calling `$product->countries->name` since you have `countries()` defined in your model and not `country()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the name from an object called '`country`'.  However, you have defined the relationship as `countries`.

Suggest you change the name of the relationship on the **Product** model to be singular, as it is a belongs to relationship:

```
public function country(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

Then, when you call :

```
{{$product->country->name}}
```

If there is a country attached by the id, you will not have an exception due to a non-object.

However, there is another problem and this will still fail in its current state.  You have defined your foreign key as `country_to` and `country_from`.  Laravel, by default in the `country()` relationship is going to look for a field called `country_id` to match to.  You will need to add the foreign key into the relationship directly for each type of relationship you want (a `countryTo()` and a `countryFrom()`) in order for it to work.

Comment: Thank you so much, I followed your advice and also instead of countryTo and countryFrom I changed it to shipping_id and receiving_id, ofcourse not before I define the foreign keys with their proper handles. Then I just called $product->shipping->name and $product->receiving->name and it worked like a charm. I have to study a little bit more the foreign key relations and how Laravel is naming them by default i.e. country() -> country_id

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the relationship function that is defined in `Product` model. The following should work:

```php
{{$product->countries->name}}
```

You're calling `->country` on product model which is never defined, hence you get the error.

**NOTE**
I would recommend you change the relationship function from plural to singular like:

`countries()` to `country()` because a product can only belong to a single country.

Hope it helps!